# How to calculate draw probabilities of Champions League 1/8?

Tags: probability

I've found a board which shows the probabilities of each possible match in the Champions League 1/8 finals. [image]

I wanted to know how those calculations were done but I can't find a way to do it. Every team can meet each other except for 3 rules :

- First of each group (names on the left) have to face the second of each group (names of the top)
- Two teams from the same country can't face each other (I.E:Barcelona and Madrid)
- Two teams from the same stage group can't face other (I.E: Atletico and Bayern)

Comment: Although it is about a previous year another SE site has some information http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262629/what-is-the-probability-of-this-exact-same-champions-league-draw

Comment: I'm trying to solve the problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41149926/4089351), but so far not very successfully.